# Adjustable current source 0-20mA for LED dimming

Tags: led, current, dimming, source

I have been searching through the site, but I have not been able find an answer.
I have an LED (rated for 14 mA at 24V, the LED is with built-in series resistor) that I need to be able to dim from completely off to fully on (0-14 mA).

A search at Mouser and Digikey did not show any simple current source IC’s that can regulate down to 0mA, so now I am looking for a discrete circuit to do the job. However, all of the circuits that I have seen have a min current higher than 0mA. The dimming/adjustment input should preferable be a voltage.

Any IC’s or discrete circuit implementation suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually you would use PWM for this, any reason you want to vary the current?

Comment: Usually, one uses a current sink/source and arranges that to provide the maximum desired brightness. Then one will apply PWM in order to adjust brightness from there down to zero.

Comment: have you googled for 'current source'? what did you find?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Make sure that the OPAMP supports input voltage down to zero.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Hamid, great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Hamid-R-Tanhaei provides one possible solution using a voltage controlled current sink circuit. Benefit of that is you can use PWM control at input to control brightness but you can also apply a constant DC voltage to set the brightness to desired amount. There are other circuits online that utilize op amp but are current sources. These are shown below.

Note for first circuit below, if you change 1 ohm to 360 ohm and have Vin from. 0 to 5V you get a range of I out of about 0 to 13.8mA. Adjust as needed.

[image]

Image source: LT1492 datahsheet

For second circuit below, you’d need a potentiometer to adjust current. You can change RE to change range of current sourcing. For example with 12V max and RE=820 ohm, you’d have a range to 14.6mA. Also here a newer rail to rail single  supply op amp would be used, not the 741 op amp.

[image]

Image source:bristolwatch.com

NOTE: For both of these circuits, and for other current source/sink circuit, you’d need to make sure that you don’t exceed max current of your device. For example since 14mA is your max. You’d have to make sure that for example for the first circuit( with 360 ohm resistor, that Vin doesn’t exceed 5V as this would create currents higher than 14mA.

As for IC that can be used there are linear LED drivers that consist of constant current source/sink which can be set to a fixed constant current and/or also be made adjustable via pulse width modulation control. For example, parts AL5801 and BCR421UW6Q. I’d recommend checking their datasheet.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards the opamp based current sources and the linear LED drivers! These were just the right solution for my problem.